# How to fill blank cells in Excel with the date of 30/06/YEAR by picking the year from the cell in the next column

Tags: excel

Consider the following table:

[image]

I have a series of blank cells with missing data. From this missing data I only have the year in the next column. I need to fill any blank cells with a standard day/month of 30/06. The year of each cell however needs to be the year in the next column. The attached file shows how my data is arranged. So at cell B 2091, the date shall be 30/06/2011 while for cell B 2098 the date shall be 30/06/2018 and at cell B 2100 the date shall be 30/06/2008.

Answer (score 1):

Filter on the blank cells in column B. Then, in the topmost cell (which I'll assume to be B1 but will likely be different), enter a formula similar to the following and fill down

```
=DATE(C1,6,30)
```

where the row number in C1 is the same as your first row of data.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with a helper column (any blank column in the same worksheet where you need the dates). In that column enter this formula in the first cell (here in row 2) and copy down.

```
=IF(ISBLANK(B2),DATE(C2,6,30),B2)
```

Then copy the ***Values*** from the helper column to the date column and delete the helper.

Below is a small macro that is doing the same job. It needs no helper column and over-writes your existing blanks. Before you run it make sure to check the values of the 2 constants at the top and the name of the worksheet (especially the latter!) against your requirements.

```
Sub WriteStandardDate()
    '293
    
    Const FirstDataRow  As Long = 2         'change to suit
    Const DateClm       As Long = 2         'change to suit
    ' year column must be adjacent to DateClm
    
    Dim R               As Long
    Dim Arr             As Variant
    Dim Rng             As Range
    
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")               ' change name as required
        Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(FirstDataRow, DateClm), _
                         .Cells(.Rows.Count, DateClm).End(xlUp)) _
                         .Resize(, 2)
        Arr = Rng.Value
        For R = 1 To UBound(Arr)
            If IsEmpty(Arr(R, 1)) Then
                Arr(R, 1) = DateSerial(Arr(R, 2), 6, 30)
            End If
        Next R
        
        Rng.Value = Arr
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Update: I used the formula suggested by Variatus: =IF(ISBLANK(B2),DATE(C2,6,30),B2) and worked fine through a helper column. There was no need to copy / paste the new dates into the Dates column. I just used the helper column as the new Dates column since full dates from the original column were not changed and got inserted in the helper column thanks to the IFBLANK portion of the formula. Thanks.